# How to mount Dropbox folder from ubuntu guest virtualbox with rw permission

Tags: linux, virtualbox, mount, dropbox

I am using windows 8.1.
I installed virtualbox and set up a virtual Ubuntu 13.10 system in it.
I want to shared the folder with windows. The folder is the Dropbox folder with rw permission.
I can successfully mount the any other folder in my windows except the Dropbox folder.
I can only mount it with readonly permission.

I use the command like

```
   sudo mount -t vboxsf sharename /home/username/mountpoint -o rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,dev
```

Why I can not mount Dropbox with rw?

Comment: Did you try the steps outlined in [this blogpost](http://tomshaws.blogspot.nl/2011/09/combining-dropbox-and-virtualbox.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Dropbox for Linux](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=linux) instead. You can install via the Ubuntu `.deb` file available through the previous link, or you can install Dropbox graphically using the Software Center program. It's much easier than trying to share a Dropbox directory across the network.